# R: find a range of values and replace them as NA in a cvs file

Tags: r

My data collected from field measurements are a bit messy and they need some clean up before further calculation.

Can you please give me an example in R to find a range of values and replace them as NA in a cvs file?

The reasonable values should between 1800 and 2200 or NA. Any values out of this range should be replaced as NA.

The dataset looks like this:

```
          timestamp        tr        ts
 1   2015-07-08 02:29:00   -40.5     1978.62
 2   2015-07-08 02:30:00   1936.74   30.5
 3   2015-07-08 02:31:00   1937.14   1978.99
 4   2015-07-08 02:32:00   1937.66   1978.83
 5   2015-07-08 02:33:00   402.4     1979.15
 6   2015-07-08 02:45:00   1937.00   1979.00
 7   2015-07-08 02:46:00   1937.75   1979.29
 8   2015-07-08 02:47:00   1937.84   1978.44
 9   2015-07-08 02:48:00   -30.23    3.5
 10  2015-07-08 02:49:00   1937.82   1978.68
 11  2015-07-08 02:50:00   1937.55   1979.60
 12  2015-07-08 02:51:00   1937.55   1979.13
 13  2015-07-08 02:52:00   1937.65   1979.12
 14  2015-07-08 02:53:00   1937.56   1978.28
 15  2015-07-08 02:54:00   1937.38   1978.99
 16  2015-07-08 02:58:00   -22.34    1978.61
 17  2015-07-08 02:59:00   1937.78   1978.85
 18  2015-07-08 03:00:00   1937.71   100.42
 19  2015-07-08 03:01:00   1937.14   1979.04
 20  2015-07-08 03:02:00   2500.00   0.13
```

Dataset after screening and replacement.

```
          timestamp        tr        ts
 1   2015-07-08 02:29:00   NA        1978.62
 2   2015-07-08 02:30:00   1936.74   NA
 3   2015-07-08 02:31:00   1937.14   1978.99
 4   2015-07-08 02:32:00   1937.66   1978.83
 5   2015-07-08 02:33:00   NA        1979.15
 6   2015-07-08 02:45:00   1937.00   1979.00
 7   2015-07-08 02:46:00   1937.75   1979.29
 8   2015-07-08 02:47:00   1937.84   1978.44
 9   2015-07-08 02:48:00   NA        NA
 10  2015-07-08 02:49:00   1937.82   1978.68
 11  2015-07-08 02:50:00   1937.55   1979.60
 12  2015-07-08 02:51:00   1937.55   1979.13
 13  2015-07-08 02:52:00   1937.65   1979.12
 14  2015-07-08 02:53:00   1937.56   1978.28
 15  2015-07-08 02:54:00   1937.38   1978.99
 16  2015-07-08 02:58:00   NA        1978.61
 17  2015-07-08 02:59:00   1937.78   1978.85
 18  2015-07-08 03:00:00   1937.71   NA
 19  2015-07-08 03:01:00   1937.14   1979.04
 20  2015-07-08 03:02:00   NA        NA
```

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: I used Matlab. It is so easy to use R. I don't want to go back to Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a similar philosophy  with @Ranalyst 's answer, but I'm using an `ifelse` approach combined with `sapply` to update multiple columns.

```
dt = read.table(text = "timestamp  tr  ts
2015-07-08   -40.5     1978.62
2015-07-08   1936.74   30.5
2015-07-08   1937.14   1978.99
2015-07-08   1937.66   1978.83
2015-07-08   402.4     1979.15
2015-07-08   1937.00   1979.00", header=T)

dt

#    timestamp      tr      ts
# 1 2015-07-08  -40.50 1978.62
# 2 2015-07-08 1936.74   30.50
# 3 2015-07-08 1937.14 1978.99
# 4 2015-07-08 1937.66 1978.83
# 5 2015-07-08  402.40 1979.15
# 6 2015-07-08 1937.00 1979.00


# select positions of columns to update
cols_to_update = 2:3

# update those columns
dt[,cols_to_update] = sapply(cols_to_update, function(x) ifelse(dt[,x] <= 1800 | dt[,x] >= 2200, NA, dt[,x]))

dt

#    timestamp      tr      ts
# 1 2015-07-08      NA 1978.62
# 2 2015-07-08 1936.74      NA
# 3 2015-07-08 1937.14 1978.99
# 4 2015-07-08 1937.66 1978.83
# 5 2015-07-08      NA 1979.15
# 6 2015-07-08 1937.00 1979.00
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I love it.

Answer (score 1):

```
# simulate some data
set.seed(123)
ts=rnorm(15,2000,300)
      ts
1  1831.857
2  1930.947
3  2467.612
4  2021.153
5  2038.786
6  2514.519
7  2138.275
8  1620.482
9  1793.944
10 1866.301
11 2367.225
12 2107.944
13 2120.231
14 2033.205
15 1833.248

# then convert all numbers less than 1800 or greater than 2200 to NA's
ts[ts <= 1800 | ts >= 2200] = NA
as.data.frame(list(ts=ts))
      ts
1  1831.857
2  1930.947
3        NA
4  2021.153
5  2038.786
6        NA
7  2138.275
8        NA
9        NA
10 1866.301
11       NA
12 2107.944
13 2120.231
14 2033.205
15 1833.248
```

or in your case if your data frame is called data

```
data$ts[data$ts <= 1800 | data$ts >= 2200] = NA
```